# How to **DISABLE** chrome's new attempts to reduce memory consumption?

Tags: google-chrome

I currently have the latest chrome and I am now facing these problems: (Google is probably doing this to save memory but I am facing many problems...)

1) **It is discarding the tabs which have been left open for a long time and reloading them only when I visit them** ... And since I have a slower Internet speed ... Its a damn big hassle....

2) **It is Not loading new tabs (Open in new tab) in the background** ... I have to click on them to load them ...

> Please tell me how to fix/disable these problems/features... (Either from chrome://flags ... or other stuffs...)

*Thanks!!*

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but try this:

chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding -> Disable

Restart Chrome.